# Prove that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $f(x+a)$ is also a polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

I am trying to prove an exercise from 'Chapter 1, Calculus Vol. I' by Apostol:
If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then show that $f(x+a)$ is also a polynomial of degree $n$.

I have outlined two proofs for this:

1. Assume $f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}c_{k}x^{k}$, which gives us  $f(x+a) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}c_{k}(x+a)^{k}$. Using the binomial expansion formula, we can expand each term and show: $$f(x+a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\sum_{i=k}^{n}{i \choose k}a^{i-k}c_i \right) x^{k}$$
2. Argue that $f(x+a)$ is a linear translation of $f(x)$ along the $x$-axis and, graphically, the functions have the same form.

I am looking for a more elegant proof not involving such heavy algebra or arguments involving higher-order objects such as graphs.

Comment: (2) isn't a proof at all, really. I think (1) is the canonical proof, and hints at the fact that we should practice this sort of algebraic manipulation with summations until it doesn't seem heavy.

Comment: Heavy algebra??? You ain't seen nothing yet!

Comment: How about that $\frac {d}{dx} f(x+a) = \frac {d}{dx} f(x)$ and $\frac {d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} f(x+a) = \frac {d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} f(x) = 0$

Comment: @DougM that is an interesting approach. The $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ derivative shows that the degree of the function is $<=n$. However, I don't think we can equate the lower order derivatives.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you for your comment. Yes, in fact, as is evident from that I am reading Apostol, I am very new to this and I need more practice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Indeed I am just opening up my eyes :D

Comment: #1 is the standard argument, and arguably the more general one. #2 is basically just hand-waving it as written, but since this is tagged `real-analysis` and assuming you know the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) you could perhaps argue that $x_k$ is a (complex) root of $f(x)$ iff $x_k-a$ is a root of $f(x+a)$ and the two have the same multiplicity. The degree of a complex polynomial equals the number of roots counting multiplicities, so $f(x)$ and $f(x+a)$ have the same degree. That said, using FTA here _is_ quite heavy-handed.

Comment: I'm not even sure that the FTA argument does the trick: it proves that $f(x+a)$ must have the same degree *if* it's a polynomial, but doesn't prove that it's a polynomial to begin with.

Comment: @GregMartin I would assume that polynomials being closed under composition has been established by that point.

Comment: That seems unlikely, given that the proof of that fact is at least as difficult as the proof (1) in the OP.

Comment: @GregMartin Fair point, but textbook exercises are sometimes exercising the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k}c_{n}x^{n}$$
$$f(x+a) = \sum_{n=0}^{k}c_{n}(x+a)^{n}$$
$$(x+a)^n = \sum_{l=0}^{n}b_{l}a^{n-l}x^{l}$$
$$f(x+a) = \sum_{n=0}^{k}c_{n}\sum_{l=0}^{n}{\gamma}_{l}x^{l}$$
gamma is the new constant since $b_{l}a^{n-l}$ is constant

rhs

$$\sum_{n=0}^{k}c_{n}\sum_{l=0}^{n}{\gamma}_{l}x^{l} = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}c_n\sum_{l=0}^n{\gamma}_{l}x^{l} + c_{k}\sum_{l=0}^{k}{\gamma}_{l}x^{l}$$
$$c_{k}\sum_{l=0}^{k}{\gamma}_{l}x^{l} = \sum_{l=0}^{k}c_{k}{\gamma}_{l}x^{l} = \sum_{l=0}^{k}{\beta}_{l}x^{l}$$

following the same recursive solution

$$f(x+a) = \sum_{l=0}^{k}{\beta}_{l}x^{l} + \sum_{l=0}^{k-1}{\beta}_{l}x^{l} + \sum_{l=0}^{k-2}{\beta}_{l}x^{l}.....$$
$$F(x+a) = \sum_{l=0}^{k}{\beta}_{l}x^{l}$$
which is a ploynomial

Comment: don't hesitate to ask if you still have doubts